# How can I write this in an if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

**I need an if statement that can determine if 2 dice do not equal each other and both dice are even. If that statement is true then player one needs to receive the greater value of points** for example a dice roll is 2 and 4, player 1 would get 4 points.

Here is my function with the if statement:

```
def game_play():
    if value1 == value2:
        player1 = player1 + (value1 + value2)
        return (player1)
    elif value1 /= value2 and == (2, 4, 6):
        if value1 > value2:
            player1 = player1 + value1
        else:
            player1 = player1 + value2
```

Comment: `value1 /= value2 and == (2, 4, 6):` is a syntax error. The second clause in the `and` should express a complete thought, but `== (2,4,6)` is at best a fragment of a thought.

Comment: Use modulo to figure out if a value is even.  `value % 2 == 0`

Comment: You don't need to (incorrectly) test `elif value1 != value2` (it's guaranteed because of the earlier `if value1 == value2` test).

Answer (score 0):

Use modulo operator for testing even

```
if value1 == value2 and value1 % 2 == 0:
    pass
```